# Find the sum of the series $\sum\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question was in my maths paper . I tried to prove that the series converges but failed to do so. Any hint are welcomed .

Comment: Is the sum made over $n$ or over $k$?

Comment: @LucaMac  over $k$

Comment: So it's $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+k)}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)…(n+k)} = n!\sum_{k = 1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+k)!}$$
Which clearly converges super-exponentially. We can express this in terms of generalized Gamma function is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\cdots(n+k)=\frac{(n+k)!}{n!}$$
from here you only need to get to $\displaystyle \sum \frac1{k!}=e$, which is easy by adding some missing terms.

Comment: for $\displaystyle \sum \frac1{k!}=e$ to be true, $k$ needs to start from $0$, otherwise $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1} \frac1{k!}=e-1$

Comment: Indeed. I nowhere specified where the summation starts, though, I just suggested the idea

Comment: The reason I raised it was, for $n=0$ it should lead to $\sum\limits_{k=1} \frac1{k!}$ and from my calculations it should be $\leq 2$, but then $e\leq 2$ doesn't makes sense :) ... it took me ~10 minutes to realise it's $e-1<2$ in fact.

Answer (score 0):

**Just focusing on convergence**, since $n+k\geq n+2, \forall k\geq2,\forall n\geq0$ we have:
$$0<\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+k)}\leq\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)^{k-1}}$$
thus 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+k)}\leq
\frac{1}{n+1}+\sum\limits_{k=2}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)^{k-1}}=\\
\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1+\sum\limits_{\color{red}{k=2}}\frac{1}{(n+2)^{k-1}}\right)=
\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1+\sum\limits_{\color{red}{k=1}}\frac{1}{(n+2)^{k}}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sum\limits_{\color{red}{k=0}}\frac{1}{(n+2)^{k}}\right)=...$$
the latter is an infinite geometric progression, or:
$$...=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+2}}=\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}$$